# Achieving high recall for smaller class in unbalanced linear svm

Tags: svm, linear-model, unbalanced-classes

I have an svm-related question.

I have an unbalanced dataset, meaning classA could be 1/10 to 1/35 of classB.
Well I am interested in getting a *linear* svm which would separate the data and would achieve the greatest possible recall of classA.

Let me show some **examples** to be more specific:

- If 1000 samples are mapped to classA by the hyperline I want to have 80%-90% of classA. This does not mean that classA would have only 1000 samples, it could have 2000 or 10000. I am not interested in the accuracy of classA, i.e. the standard criterion to get the more samples of classA by svm out of the total samples belonging to classA.
- If I can get 100 samples of classA and no of classB it would be preferable than getting 500 samples of classA and 500 of classB.

My question is how do I choose this hyperplane. I have tried the following:

1. I used unbalanced weights for the samples (inverting the class cardinalities) but I can get high classA accuracy but low recall.
2. I tries to use the default weights, i.e. for all being 1, but I got peculiar results:
   when run on *train set* for all samples it gets an accuracy of 95% (as expected since dataset is unbalanced). **BUT** if checked in classA members it gives 0%!

So have you got any ideas besides playing around with weights?

P.S.1 I am using liblinear (in matlab if that matters). 
P.S.2 I know svm optimization criterion basically does not account for what I am looking for since margin maximization maximizes accuracy but I thought I would give it a try.

Comment: I **strongly** suggest against optimizing recall exclusively. Without accounting for anything else, the 'optimal' classifier would simply always yield `classA`, with maximal recall (1).

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood the use of the word recall in the above context. I did not count it on the cardinality of classA but rather on the samples assigned to classA. Maybe the recall should have been "recall". That's why I gave the examples above.